# Ряженный и ряженый

Tags: орфография

Надо было написать "ряжен(Н)ые казаки", то есть, люди, одетые в костюмы казаков и выдающие себя за них. И что-то я споткнулась: два тут Н или одно?
Спасибо

Comment: >Надо было написать "ряжен(Н)ые казаки", то есть, люди, одетые в костюмы казаков и выдающие себя за них. И что-то я споткнулась

И я споткнулся, "но не разбился", а задумался. Ряженые парни, девки и, аналогично, казаки (этнические служивые) — это люди в маскарадных костюмах, причём произвольных (до вздора). А люди, одетые в казачьи костюмы да с соответствующими повадками и *тугаментами*,— кто они? Настоящие казаки или всё же *засланные*? Уместно ли к ним вообще ставить подобные определения?

Comment: Особенно меня умиляют их звания и ордена. Откуда они их взяли?

Answer (score 3):

Пишем "ряженые казаки". Это форма, образованная от бесприставочного глагола несовершенного вида и не имеющая зависимых слов. В этом случае причастие (НН) переходит в прилагательное (Н), так как обозначает постоянный во времени признак (в отличие от причастия, которое всегда обозначает процессуальный, то есть развернутый во времени признак).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

1. Ряженые казаки – это не настоящие казаки, а  люди, одетые как казаки. В то же время существуют, наверное, настоящие казаки, которые надевают национальные костюмы на праздник. Этих людей вряд ли можно назвать ряжеными казаками.
2. В орфографическом словаре присутствуют обе формы: причастие ряженный и прилагательное ряженый. Мы говорим: «ряженые (прил.) казаки» и «люди, ряженные (прич.) казаками», то есть выбор Н или НН определяется наличием зависимых слов. Есть еще существительное «ряженые», например: Ряженые  ходили на Масленицу по дворам.
3. По поводу суффикса прилагательного  ЕНН. Это суффикс отыменного прилагательного: время – временный, огонь – огненный, внутри – внутренний. Отглагольные прилагательные имеют только суффикс ЕН, а  отглагольная форма с суффиксом ЕНН – это уже причастие.

Comment: А почему Н? Ведь с суф. прилагательных -ЕНН- обычно НН. Ну, кроме ветреный.